# What mode in EVP for AES-128 should I use for cryptanalysis of AES?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, openssl, modes-of-operation

I've been trying to use AES from OpenSSL and got to know that I need to use the EVP-based implementations rather than the `AES_*`.

I need to use AES-128 implementation to generate bitstreams, essentially passing various keys, and plaintexts to analyze the ciphertext generated for cryptanalysis of the algorithm. I went through the Question, [How do I decide what mode to use?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17820/how-do-i-decide-what-mode-to-use) which linked to the NIST documentation and an answer. I unfortunately am unable to decide on what implementation would be good for me to use.

I will be using plaintexts of the order of `2^14- 2^16` bits. I wish to know what would be the best implementation to use.

(TLDR: Need to use AES-128 implementations for cryptanalysis for academia, not sure which implementation from `EVP_AES` to use, will be using large plain texts)

Comment: well what are you trying to analyze?

Comment: @user253751 the pattern of the ensuing bitstream, its linear complexity, and doing further analysis

Comment: Ensuing bit stream using what? AES is a block cipher. There are things like Monte Carlo tests but I wonder [how useful those would be](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68680/whats-the-reason-for-monte-carlo-tests-for-block-ciphers). [Linear complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_cryptanalysis) is a property of the mathematical definition of a block cipher, you don't need any implementation for that. That leaves "further analysis". I would propose you do that after gaining some more understanding about how block ciphers operate.

Comment: By the way, no idea why you have a specific set of plaintext, but I wonder why you would not just write 2 KiB to 8 KiB.

Comment: Since I am working with 128-bit keys, I want to use plaintext of the order of 4n^2 ideally, which amounts to 2^16 bits. As for "further analysis" I wish to compute the Maximal Order Complexity, the end goal is to check how vulnerability in the keys and the plaintext used affect the weakness of the ciphertext. I shall read through the posts about the Monte Carlo tests linked.

Comment: AES is considered secure. You won't get any results. If you want to start anywhere, you probably want to use a reduced round version. For that you need the source code, not any high level function.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it,

Comment: @Luce AES is a block cipher. To encrypt a bitstream with a block cipher, you use a mode. If you are talking about streams this implies you have already chosen some specific mode. AES encrypts blocks; AES-CBC (for example) encrypts streams. (And then you also need a padding scheme in order to round up the stream length so it's a multiple of the block size.)